# VoIP implementation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, voip

- How to implement VoIP in iPhone using code?
- Is there any code to    implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org) :). It's a SIP library written in C. You must compile the source for iphone, it is described in the docs [here](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started). After that take a look at a very basic sample application [here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm). It isn't very hard to use even if you don't know C or how to compile libraries.

**UPDATE** Beware that PJSIP uses GPL as it's license.

Comment: How do you get around the fact that pjsip is GPL?  Doesn't that require you to release your app as GPL as well?

Comment: I experimented with this, without knowing anything about the license. Later we decided not to include VOIP support not because of the license. To be honest I never checked it. I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/) which is described as Home of the World's first free SIP/VoIP application for iPhone and iPod Touch 1 and 2.